# Let $L$ be a linear operator on vector space $R^3$ defined with $L(x,y,z)=(-x+2y+(3-c)z,(c+1)x-y+2z,2x+2y-z),$ with $c$ from $R$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices, normal-operator

Prove that $L$ is symmetric operator of euclidean space $R^3$ with standard dot product if and only if $c=1$.

So I think i proved that if $c=1$ then $L$ is a symmetric operator.
Its matrix in standard basis (which is of course orthonormal) is symmetric, so does that means that $L$ is symmetric operator?

How can I use the fact that $L$ is symmetric with standard dot product to prove that $c=1$?
This is my first question here and english is not my native language so I'm not sure I used right
terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix representing $L$ with respect to the standard basis $\mathcal{E}$ (which is orthonormal with respect to the standard dot product) is given by

$$ [L]_{\mathcal{E}} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 & 3 - c \\
c+1 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Now, use the theorem that $L$ is a symmetric operator **iff** $[L]_{\mathcal{E}}$ is a symmetric matrix. This clearly occurs iff $c = 1$.

Comment: In my book theorem says that operator is symmetric  iff its matrix in every orthonrmal basis is symmetric. If its matrix is symmetric in some orthonormal basis, is it symmetric in every other? If so why?

Comment: @Gregory: Yes, being symmetric with respect to a single orthonormal basis is equivalent to being symmetric with respect to all of them. The reason is that if $\alpha,\beta$ are two orthonormal basis then the change of basis matrix $P$ is orthonormal. Thus, if $A$ is symmetric then $P^{-1}AP = P^TAP$ is also symmetric because $(P^TAP)^T = P^T A^T (P^T)^T = P^T A P$.

Comment: That makes sense . Thank you